# Glassfish service throws an error

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, service, glassfish

I have successfully installed a Glassfish service that runs on my server.

When I try to access the application, I get an HTTP 500 error :

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required`

When I launch NetBeans and Glassfish, it starts automatically (I assume it finds the sevice that is already running) and I can launch my application without problems.

Have you ever encountered this problem ? I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the answer, I post it there in case someone does read this topic.

I had to set another parameter to the glassfish conf, AS_JAVA, and give it the path to the JDK.

I then got a 404 error.

So I put my .war file in the glassfish's autodeploy folder, and it now works like a charm.